# Error: The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I am coding a program that is to solve a specific math problem. Below is a code snippet from the program ('...' means that I've cut in the code):

```
Console.Write("First Natrual Number: ");
long N1 = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

...

Console.Write("Upper Product Limit (to & excluding): ");
long L = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//Determines upper limits of sums.
double L1_temp = (L / N1);

...

if ((L%N1) ==  0)
{
 long L1 = Convert.ToInt64(L1_temp - 1);
}else
{
 long L1 = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(L1_temp));
}

...

//Calculating Product Sums.

long S1 = 0;
long a = L1; •
while(a > 0)
{
 S1 += (N1 * a);
 a -= 1;
}
```

When I try building the program in Visual Studio I get the error "The name 'L1' does not exist in the current context". The line marked with a bullet point (•) is the line on which the mentioned error is displayed.

Does anyone know why this error occurs, given that 'L1' is defined in the above if statement, and how to solve it?

Comment: @KClaesson you need to go back and read the `C# Basics Tutorial` and focus on the section about `Scope` and what it means, you declare another variable inside of an `if()` block, that same variable does not have the same scope as the one declared outside of the `if()` code block the error tells you what the problem is..

Comment: @MethodMan Are you referring to a specific tutorial? If so, would you mind providing a link?

Comment: @MethodMan: Is there a particular tutorial you had in mind? Because a great many tutorials define scope *wrong*.

Comment: Scope is *the region of program text in which a thing can be referred to by its unqualified name*. Many tutorials confuse scope -- a compile-time concept -- with *lifetime*, a runtime concept.

Comment: @EricLippert I respect your comment

Answer (score 2):

Names are scoped to blocks in C#.  When you have

```
{
   var n = whatever; 
}
...
{
    var n = whatever;
}
```

Then you have **two variables both called n**.

Put the variable declaration at the block level that you intend to use the variable at:

```
long l1;
if (whatever)
{
   l1 = whatever;
} 
else
{
   l1 = whatever;
}
// l1 is still in scope here.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this

```
long L1;
if ((L%N1) ==  0)
{
  L1 = Convert.ToInt64(L1_temp - 1);
}else
{
  L1 = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(L1_temp));
}
```

in your code L1 (2 different ones) only exists inside the if and else conditional blocks

Answer (score 0):

L1 is being created inside of the If statements. They do not exist outside of that context/scope.

Instead do this:

```
long L1;
if ((L%N1) ==  0)
{
 L1 = Convert.ToInt64(L1_temp - 1);
}else
{
 L1 = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(L1_temp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring L1 outside of the if else statement like this:

```
long L1 = 0;

if ((L%N1) ==  0) L1 = Convert.ToInt64(L1_temp - 1);
else L1 = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(L1_temp));
```